# Как сделать из JSON в BSON и отправить пакет?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как сделать из JSON в BSON? И если мне не изменяет память, то нужно там еще вес файла и дату указывать, в инете похожего не нашел.

мой BSON который я получаю:

> b'oQAAAJ0AAAADbTAAjAAAAAJJRAAEAAAAUklpAANySQB3AAAAEENvbGxlY3RhYmxlSUQAAQAAABBCbG9ja1R5cGUAAQAAABBBbW91bnQAAQAAABBJbnZlbnRvcnlUeXBlAAAAAAABUG9zWAAAAADAHgU0QAFQb3NZAAAAACCFi0FACElzR2VtAAAQR2VtVHlwZQAAAAAAAAAQbWMAAQAAAAA='

и это я перевожу в JSON:

> { "ID" : "RIi", "rI" : { "CollectableID" : 1, "BlockType" : 1,
> "Amount" : 1, "InventoryType" : 0, "PosX" : 20.020000457763671875,
> "PosY" : 35.090000152587890625, "IsGem" : false, "GemType" : 0 } }

в JSONe меняю значения, а как перевести его в BSON и отправить, при этом нужно ли указывать конечный размер файла и что еще нужно?

Comment: А как вы из `BSON` переводите в `JSON`? По идее `bson.encode(json_)`

Comment: b64String = base64.b64encode(data)

packet = b64String[16:]